# Using Azure AD MSAL as only authentication solution for SPA

Tags: security, authentication, azure

I have an Angular SPA and I spun up my own basic form-based authentication using a `.net core web API` and `SQL server` to store user accounts / hashed and salted credentials. This is obviously not an ideal way to handle auth and it was only meant to be temporary. I have since gotten a request to integrate Azure AD, SSO for organizations using the software already. Since I wanted to move in this direction anyways, I think this is the perfect opportunity to rethink my auth solution.

I drew up this plan:

[image]

As detailed, I want all user access to be handled through Microsoft accounts, and do away with my custom solution. Now, I still need a way to make sure that only accounts allowed by me have access to the software; I plan to do this in the orange layer above. Once a user signs into an account via the login.microsoftonline.com portal, I would then validate that the email address is associated with an account in my SQL database already. If not, I would not allow them access to the software / secure route. The SQL database account entries will be added by me manually.

I figured this was a great solution because it removes the need for me to store sensitive password / user information in my database. I would only be storing an some ID's (Email address, etc...) to Microsoft accounts that I allow in.

**So a few questions:**

1. Is this a proper SSO solution?
2. Is there any apparent major flaws in handling things this way?
3. Should I use the email address in my SQL as the user identifier? or some
   other ID given by Azure AD?